# Animation will not render in 2.83 or 2.9 despite set keyframes being set in viewport and pose mode

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging, eevee-render-engine

Here's the link to my file (don't worry about the textures): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PyYTDLBEUdPtc7opcM9FJ6vaLi8TXXWD/view?usp=sharing
The rig isn't totally mine, it's a modified version of RoyalSkiesLLC's rig that I adapted for my own use. The problem is that in any version newer than 2.82 the rendered animation will only show whatever pose I had on my viewport timeline throughout the render. For example if I had my timeline set to frame 1 the whole rendered animation from frames 1-30 will only show my pose from frame 1. I have no idea what to make of it, I spent a long time customizing the rig, but I would have to go back to 2.82 to use it. For mor current versions (which I would like to use) may have to construct my own from scratch or through rigify or blenrig, but that would lead to even more tweaking and customization not to mention my inability to customize generated rigs to my liking. I would appreciate any help, thanks! [image: older image]

Comment: It rendered for me in both 2.83.4 and 2.91 from a few days ago. The only thing I changed was setting the output to png instead of ffmpeg. There does only seem to be 10 frames of animation set on the character.

Comment: Ron Jensen Odd, my original settings were PNG, but it never worked on my rig. (R 5 1600 AF, RX 580, 32 GB DDR4)

Comment: Ron Jensen Actually it seems that the wiggle bone add-on was the problem, for some demented reason. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I thought I had wigglebone. I guess it disappeared when I updated 2.83->2.83.4 Glad you found it.

Comment: There is no need to add "solved" as part of the title. Accept the answer that solves your issue instead.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, disabling the wiggle bone add-on did the trick, it was all my fault.